# Accessing a preloaded array based on index

Tags: jquery

Here's my markup

```
<div id="pics">
    <img src="http://someimageimage.jpg" />
    <img src="http://someimageimage2.jpg" />
    <img src="http://someimageimage3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Currently I have this code:

```
function loop(i) {
    var $img = $("#pics img");
    $img.eq(idx).fadeIn(2000, function () {
    // code comes here
    }
}

loop(0);
```

This is working fine. Now instead of using those image tags, I have to change it to use picture pre loading. So I put the links in an array

```
// array of images
var picarr = ['http://someimageimage.jpg',
              'http://someimageimage2.jpg',
              'http://someimageimage3.jpg',
              'http://someimageimage4.jpg'];

prepicload(picarr); // pre load the pics          

function prepicload(picarr) {
    $(picarr).each(function () {
        $('<img/>').attr('src', this).appendTo('body').hide();
    });
}
```

**How will I now change my code to access this pre loaded picture instead of the image selector?**

```
function loop(i) {
    var $img = $("#pics img");
    $img.eq(idx).fadeIn(2000, function () {
    // code comes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you  add a class to the images and use it as a selector

```
function prepicload(picarr) {
    $(picarr).each(function () {
        $('<img/>', {
            src: this,
            'class': 'pics'
        }).hide().appendTo('body');
    });
}
```

then

```
function loop(i) {
    var $img = $("img.pics");
    $img.eq(idx).fadeIn(2000, function () {
    // code comes here
    })
}
```

another solution will be is to use a shared variable like

```
//use a shared variable to store all the preloaded images
var $preimgs = $();

function prepicload(picarr) {
    $(picarr).each(function () {
        var $img = $('<img/>', {
            src: this,
                'class': 'pics'
        }).hide().appendTo('body');
    });
    $preimgs = $preimgs.add($img);
}

function loop(i) {
    $preimgs.eq(idx).fadeIn(2000, function () {
        // code comes here
    })
}
```

Comment: How are we absolutely sure that we are accessing the preloading images?

Comment: @Thomasmkov that will depend on whether another images with the same class is loaded in the site

Comment: what will happen then? What about the other preloaded pics with different classes?

Comment: @Thomasmkov what do you mean by preloaded images... is it the same as images loaded by the method `prepicload`? if it is then all of them will have the same class... in that case this should be fine

Comment: makes sense. By the way you have given two methods to do the same. Which of your methods is good from a best practice point of view and why?

Comment: @Thomasmkov under the given circumstances I may opt for #2 because in #1 the selector is evaluated every time but in #2 we are using a cached set of objects

Comment: In method 1 doesn't $img refer to cached variable? Isn't that good for perf. How do you say that we aren't using a cached set of objects in option1

Comment: because that variable is created on every call to the method... it can be called a cached one if it can be moved out of the method to a shared scope

Comment: one last Q. If say there was no array and I had to preload directly from the <div id="pics"> how would I?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41233/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-thomasmkov)

Comment: I have described the problem on chat

Comment: are you on chat. It's pretty late here. 1.00 AM

Comment: @Thomasmkov did you sent the mail?